# How to properly save a WordPress option containing HTML code?

Tags: wordpress

Here's a screenshot of what the problem looks like: 
[image]

And the HTML of that part of the WordPress options page looks like this:
[image]

So, in the WordPress admin area, I entered a piece of HTML code (to have a clickable link as the output on the frontend).

This was the code I had entered into that text input field on the backend:

```
<a title="Website Design London" href="../../website-design/">Website Design</a>
```

And while on the frontend that link is displaying OK, I'm seeing this mess (see screenshot) on the backend.

As far as I can tell the relevant PHP code is this:

```
$this->text(
    'workdone',
    esc_html__( 'Work done', 'mytheme' )
);
```

So, what is the proper way to save an option that contains HTML code?

And how can I fix the mess shown on the screenshot?

Comment: So the value in the back-end is returning the value of whatever you put in - so when you close the `"`, it is closing the `value` and extending beyond that. What sort of fields did you use for this?

Comment: @GavinThomas On the backend, it's a normal text input field as shown in the screenshot. On the frontend, it is displaying a clickable link.

Comment: You should use the [esc_attr](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_attr/) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and this code is working for me:

```
// render service label
public function render_service_label() {
    $value = get_option( 'wbk_service_label', '' ); 
    $value = htmlspecialchars( $value );
    $html = '<input type="text" id="wbk_service_label" name="wbk_service_label" value="'.$value.'" >';
        $html .= '<p class="description">' . __( 'Service label', 'wbk' ) . '</p>';
        echo $html;
}
// validate service label
public function validate_service_label( $input ) {
    $allowed_tags = array(
        //formatting
        'strong' => array(),
        'em'     => array(),
        'b'      => array(),
        'i'      => array(),
        'br'      => array(),
        //links
        'a'     => array(
            'href' => array(),
            'class' => array()
        ),
        //links
        'p'     => array(
            'class' => array()
        )
    );
    $input =  wp_kses( $input, $allowed_tags );
    return  $input;
}
```

So, in the dashboard options page I use `htmlspecialchars` function

In frontend page I use like this:

```
$label = get_option( 'wbk_service_label',  __( 'Select service', 'wbk' ) );
```